# Merging two datasets with repeated IDs

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataset, pandas-merge

I want to merge two datasets using pandas. The code works but the output is not quite what I was expecting because as I'm merging based on Id's, one can appear multiple times but have different values in other columns.

My df1 is the following:

| SubscriberKey | SubscriberId | MONTH | INCOME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96346d046d42d923ed97d974f26addce04fa7324b3e1f9e69a31f297073ca06f | 125557370 | 4 | 204 |
| f75e979a030f595ba091f0a060135b733c98345b62836a278e221f503f879057 | 125557375 | 7 | 329 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 3 | 144 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 6 | 82 |

Where each row correspond to one user. However as in df2, there can be more than one entry per user, because each entry corresponds to the income per month of one user. Having said this, I want to merge another datset into this one using based on the Subscriber Id. The dataset I would like to merge is df2:

| SubscriberId | MONTH | SENT_EMAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **125557388** | 4 | 1 |
| **125557388** | 8 | 1 |
| **125557388** | 1 | 1 |
| **125557388** | 6 | 1 |
| 125557400 | 4 | 1 |
| 125557400 | 6 | 1 |

As you can see **this user** appears 4 times in this one, where we can see how many emails each user sent in a month. I used the code **pd.merge(df1, df2, on='SubscriberId)** and got the following result:

| SubscriberKey | SubscriberId | Month_x | Income | Month_y | SENT_EMAILS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f75e979a030f595ba091f0a060135b733c98345b62836a278e221f503f879057 | 125557375 | 7 | 329 | 2 | 1 |
| f75e979a030f595ba091f0a060135b733c98345b62836a278e221f503f879057 | 125557375 | 7 | 329 | 5 | 1 |
| f75e979a030f595ba091f0a060135b733c98345b62836a278e221f503f879057 | 125557375 | 7 | 329 | 6 | 2 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 3 | 144 | 4 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 3 | 144 | 8 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 3 | 144 | 1 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 3 | 144 | 6 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 6 | 82 | 4 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 6 | 82 | 8 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 6 | 82 | 1 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | **125557388** | 6 | 82 | 6 | 1 |

What do I need to add to my code so that the end result looks like this:

| SubscriberKey | SubscriberId | MONTH | INCOME | SENT_EMAILS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | 125557388 | 4 |  | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | 125557388 | 8 |  | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | 125557388 | 1 |  | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | 125557388 | 6 | 82 | 1 |
| 9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd | 125557388 | 3 | 144 |  |

I want to avoid duplicating the MONTH column and for it to only be filled with either its "sent_emails" part or the "income part", not all the possible combinations based on the Id.

Comment: Your question is too long and has too much data, try to simplify and shorten your question

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
d = df1.set_index("SubscriberId")["SubscriberKey"].to_dict()
tmp = df1.merge(df2, on=["MONTH", "SubscriberId"]).drop_duplicates()
​
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
            .loc[lambda x: x["SubscriberId"].isin(tmp["SubscriberId"])]
            .groupby(["SubscriberId", "MONTH"], as_index=False, sort=False).first() 
            .assign(SubscriberKey= lambda x: x["SubscriberId"].map(d))
             [list(df1.columns) + ["SENT_EMAILS"]]
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                                                      SubscriberKey  SubscriberId  MONTH  INCOME  SENT_EMAILS
0  9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd     125557388      3  144.00          NaN
1  9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd     125557388      6   82.00         1.00
2  9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd     125557388      4     NaN         1.00
3  9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd     125557388      8     NaN         1.00
4  9f355d3154658f70ea6104cf4d5581f1c57c28c956dcbd49370e3d004ea8ecbd     125557388      1     NaN         1.00
```

Comment: Hi! First of all I want to thank you for your help. However, I just noticed that something is missing in my post. In the last table (my desired output), a '1' is missing right after the 82, because in the df we can see that for that month the user received 1 email. I just checked my resulting csv and indeed every row where there's supposed to be a number for income AND for 'sent_emails', the sent_emails part is missing. Could you help me correct this issue please. Thank you again!

Comment: I just added the '1' in the 'sent_emails' column of the last table. Just to let you know that it wasn't there before :)

Comment: You're welcome ;). I updated my answer with something that should give you the expected output.

Comment: Your new code worked just as asked, thank you so much!! One more question tho, compared to your original answer, many observations were lost in the resulting csv, any idea why?

Comment: I think that’s because I ignored the presence of the SubscriberKey while approaching your problem in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['SubscriberId', 'MONTH'], how='left')
```

This should work!